# Identify the error record while inserting in Salesforce using simple salesforce

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, simple-salesforce

I am using the simple Salesforce library to load data from S3 to Salesforce using Databricks. I am utilizing the bulk API to perform the data load. However, when I attempt to insert data into Salesforce, if any row violates a Salesforce object constraint, such as having a Null value in a Not Null field, that particular record is not inserted, and the remaining rows are loaded without causing the notebook to fail. Now, I would like to capture these failed records in a separate file.

One approach I could take is to read the Salesforce data and then join it with our source data to identify the error records. However, this would add extra overhead to the main process. Is there another way we could achieve this?
This is the sample output I am getting after inserting record
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
We are working on similar things at my work environment. We are pushing data from databricks to Salesforce. So we are leveraging deltalake to save those errors in a table.

I convert dataframe data into a list of records. Here is the sample code, I used to capture the errors.

def update_salesforce_records(sf: Salesforce, object_name: str, external_id_field: str, records: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> Dict[str, int]:
    updated_records_count = 0
    failed_records_count = 0
    failed_records = []

    # Update the records in Salesforce using the bulk API and store the result
    result = getattr(sf.bulk, object_name).update(records, batch_size='auto', use_serial=True)

    # Add the external ID field value to each dictionary in the result list and count the number of updated and failed records
    for r in result:
        r[external_id_field] = records[result.index(r)][external_id_field]

        if r['success']:
            updated_records_count += 1
        else:
            # Create a dictionary representing the failed record and append it to the failed_records list
            failed_record = {
                'Table_Name': object_name,
                'External_ID': r.get(external_id_field),
                'Timestamp': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                'Error_Message': r.get('errors')[0].get('message')
            }
            failed_records.append(failed_record)
            failed_records_count += 1

    return {"updated_records_count": updated_records_count, "failed_records_count": failed_records_count, "failed_records": failed_records}


# Function to create  delta lake table in datbricks with reorder of columns
def create_delta_table(database_name, table_name, column_order, data):
    """
    Creates a Delta Lake table in Databricks with a specified database name, table name, and column order.
    Appends the new data to the existing table if it exists.

    Args:
        database_name (str): The name of the database to create the table in.
        table_name (str): The name of the table to create.
        column_order (list of str): The desired order of columns in the table.
        data (list of dict): The data to populate the table with.

    Returns:
        None
    """
    spark.sql(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {database_name}")
    spark.sql(f"USE {database_name}")
    
    # Create a DataFrame from the list of data
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
    
    # Reorder the columns in the DataFrame
    df = df.select(column_order)
    
    # Append the new data to the existing Delta Lake table
    df.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable(table_name)



# Create a Delta Lake table to store the failed records for future reference if any failed records exist
if update_results['failed_records_count'] > 0:
    db_name = 'sf_errors'
    delta_table_name = 'sf_update_errors'
    column_order = ['Table_Name', 'External_ID', 'Timestamp', 'Error_Message']
    create_delta_table(db_name, delta_table_name, column_order, update_results['failed_records'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).